# How to prevent Notepad++ encoding hex character?

Tags: json, encoding, hex, notepad++, editor

I have this JSON string in notepad++ (v8.4.8 - 64 bit)

```
{
    "data" : "\u0040"
}
```

Then, I format it to JSON structure using the JSON Viewer option from the menu.

[image]

After that, the data's value is encoded as below.

```
{
    "data": "@"
}
```

I want to keep the data's value as `"\u0040"` after formatting the JSON string. Is there a plugin or setting to do that?

Comment: What do you really want? Char hex 40 is `@` so that looks correct. Did you mean to write `"\\u0040"`? And please [edit] the question to show things as text, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that it is a plugin with only a few setting options.

Quoted from: [JSONViewer for Notepad++](https://github.com/kapilratnani/JSON-Viewer)

> The JSONViewer plugin for Notepad++ is meant to display a JSON string in a Treeview. It also marks the error position in case of parsing errors. That's it!!!

In my experience the plugin works very well. But this behavior seems to be a known bug.

```
{"FreeTextInput":"\u003Cscript\u003Ealert(\u0022links\u0022);\u003C/script\u003E"}
```

is resulting in:

```
{
    "FreeTextInput": "<script>alert(\"links\");</script>"
}
```

Please have a look at:

- [Format JSON replaces unicode characters code with the actual unicode character](https://github.com/kapilratnani/JSON-Viewer/issues/78)

> The bug is that "Format Json" is unescaping the escaped characters / and u**** in strings, instead of leaving them in the original escaped form.

A related one is:

- [Switching from compressed json string to pretty print mode looses quotes for forward slashes](https://github.com/kapilratnani/JSON-Viewer/issues/104)

At the moment you have to decide for your needs how to deal with the behavior.